# Open file and read to find first instance of number. Python

Tags: python

Im stuck on a problem for an assignment, I need to write a program that opens a file on my computer, and scans that file for the first instance of a number. Once it is found it will return

The first number in , filenm is x

otherwise it will say there is no number in filenm.

My code so far is below:
When i run it no matter what it always says theres no number :(

```
filenm = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")
datain=open(filenm,"r")

try:
    c=datain.read(1)
    result = []

    for line in datain:
        c=datain.read(1)

        while int(c) >= 0:
            c = datain.read(1)
            result.append(c)


except:
    pass

    if len(result) > 0:
            print "The first number is",(" ".join(result))+" . "
    else:
            print "There is no number in" , filenm + "."
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct?  (I doubt you pasted it correctly.)

Comment: Your catch-all except is masking the real error.

Comment: You are consuming input in more ways than you may realize.  for line in datain is consuming a line.

Comment: huh? im a bit confused now. i thought that line tells it to read each line.

Comment: It says to set up a loop where a line of input is read into `line` every time through the loop. Then you ignore the input that was read into `line` and read one more byte into `c`.

Answer (score 2):

That's all you need:

```
import re

with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        s=re.search(r'\d+',line)
        if s:
            print(s.group())
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

1. open the file;
2. read it in a loop char-by-char;
3. check if the char is digit, print whatever you want;
4. it means there are no numbers in the file, if end-of-file is reached, print "no numbers"

Use `<string>.isdigit()` method to check if the given string (a single character in your case) is a digit.

Comment: @justin You should check each char you read from the file. `c.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend mixing iterating through a file

```
for line in datain:
```

with using the read method (or any similar one)

```
c=datain.read(1)
```

Just stick with one or the other. Personally, I would go with iterating here.

Comment: still it says theres no number :(

Comment: Well, just taking it out won't solve your problem. You need to look at what your code is actually doing. Try going through it line by line in the interactive mode or use the pdb debugger. We're trying to help you find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

readlines() method returns a list of all the lines in the file. You can then iterate trough the list of characters in each line:

```
filenm = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")
datain=open(filenm,"r")

try:

    result = []

    for line in datain.readlines():
        print 'line: ' + line
        for each in line:
            try:
                # attempt casting a number to int
                int(each)
                # if it worked it add it to the result list
                result.append(each)
            except:
                pass
except:
    pass

print result
if len(result) > 0:
   print "The first number is",(" ".join(result[0]))+". "
else:
   print "There is no number in" , filenm + "."
```

This will only work with the first number character it finds, not sure if you actually need to extract multi digit numbers.

Comment: say the first number is 20. it only shows 2. How do i make it show 20?

Comment: @justin, it depends on how your file is formatted. If you want to just search for '20' anywhere, then you can just use string searching methods. You could also use regular expressions to find the 20. If the numbers are separated by spaces (or some common delimiter), then you can use the split() method on each line and iterate through that array. It's up to you to decide what is best to do given the known input.

Comment: @justin You could have a temporary "buffer" variable to which you can keep adding digit chars until you hit a non-digit. Once you hit the non-digit character result.append() it and continue. 

Make sure you do this if you hit the end of the file as well (in case the number was the last thing in the file). 

Another way would be to use regular expression grouping but that may be out of the scope of your exercise.

Comment: well the file opens and the first number is 20 in the date.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

1) As others noted, don't mask the exception. It would be better to let it be thrown - at least that way you find out what went wrong, if something went wrong.

2) You **do** want to read the file a line at a time, using `for line in file:`. The reason for this is that the numbers you want to read are basically "words" (things separated by spaces), and there isn't a built-in way to read the file a word at a time. `file.read(1)` reads a single byte (i.e. character, for an ASCII file), and then you have to put them together into words yourself, which is tedious. It's much easier to tell Python to split a line into words. At least, I'm assuming here that you're not supposed to pick out the "20" from "spam ham20eggs 10 lobster thermidor".

`.readlines()` is somewhat redundant; it's a convenience for making a list of the lines in the file - but we don't need that list; we just need the lines one at a time. There is a function defined called `.xreadlines()` which does that, but it's deprecated - because we can just use `for line in file:`. Seriously - just keep it simple.

3) `int` in Python will not return a negative value if the input is non-numeric. It will throw an exception. Your code does not handle that exception properly, because it would break out of the loop. There is no way to tell Python "keep going from where you threw the exception" - and there shouldn't be, because how is the rest of the code supposed to account for what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code isn't too far off. There are a number of problems. One big one is that the `try/except` hides errors from you which might have help you figure things out yourself. Another was that you're reading the file with a mixture of a line at a time (and ignoring its contents entirely) as well as a character at a time.

There also seems to be a misunderstand on your part about what the `int()` function does when given a non-numeric character string, what it does is raise an exception rather than returning something less than 0. While you *could* enclose a call to it it in a `try/except` with the `except` being specifically for `ValueError`, in this case however it would be easier to just check ahead of time to see if the character is a digit since all you want to do is continue doing that until one that isn't is seen.

So here's one way your code could be revised that would address the above issues:

```
import string

filenm = raw_input("Enter a file name: ")
datain = open(filenm,"r")

# find first sequence of one or more digits in file
result = []
while True:
    c = datain.read(1)

    while c in string.digits:  # digit?
        result.append(c)
        c = datain.read(1)

    if c == "" or len(result) > 0:  # end-of-file or a number has been found
        break  # get out of loop

if len(result) > 0:
    print "The first number is'", "".join(result) + "'."
else:
    print "There is no number in'", filenm + "'."

close(datain)
```